# how do i make the leaderboard work? there is incorrect syntax

Tags: python

I am making a 2 player dice game and at the end it has a leaderboard function.

I cannot seem to make it work as I am inexperienced and can't work around the problem. I have stated which line the system flagged up as being incorrect but there may be more after that point.

Any advice or fixes would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
  ## external file for scores ##

winner=(winner_user, winner_points)
f=open("winner.txt","a")
f.write(''.join(winner)) ##this line is the issue##
f.write("\n")
f.close()


## external file leaderboard ##

f=open("leaderboard.txt","r")
leaderboard=[line.replace("\n",'')]
for line in f.readlines():



 for idx,item in enumerate(leaderboard):
     if item.split(", ")[1]==winner[1] and int(item.split(", ")[0]) <int(winner[0]):
         leaderboard[idx]="{}, {}".format(winner[0],winner[1])

     else:
         pass

### sorts and reverses leaderboard ###


leaderboard.sort(reverse=true)

with open("leaderboard.txt","w") as f:
        for item in leaderboard:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Can you try your code with moving your line ```leaderboard = [line.replace("\n", '')]``` into your for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
winner=(winner_user, winner_points)
f=open("winner.txt","a")
f.write(''.join(winner)) ##this line is the issue##
```

I suspect the problem is that `winner_points` is an integer and can't be implicitly concatenated with the string. You should use 
`winner=(winner_user, str(winner_points))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

Have changed:

- `leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)`
- `winner=(winner_user, str(winner_points))`
- `leaderboard = [line.replace("\n", '')]` inside the loop

```
  ## external file for scores ##

winner=(winner_user, str(winner_points))
f=open("winner.txt","a")
f.write(''.join(winner)) ##this line is the issue##
f.write("\n")
f.close()


## external file leaderboard ##

f=open("leaderboard.txt","r")
for line in f.readlines():
  leaderboard = [line.replace("\n", '')]
  for idx,item in enumerate(leaderboard):
     if item.split(", ")[1]==winner[1] and int(item.split(", ")[0]) <int(winner[0]):
         leaderboard[idx]="{}, {}".format(winner[0],winner[1])

     else:
         pass

### sorts and reverses leaderboard ###


leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)

with open("leaderboard.txt","w") as f:
        for item in leaderboard:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: What have you changed here?

Comment: IMHO, could be really interesting to specify what you corrected in your answer, instead of just posting a corrected code.

Comment: ```leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)```, ```winner=(winner_user, str(winner_points))``` and ```leaderboard = [line.replace("\n", '')]``` inside the loop

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav mention what you changed in the question itself not in the comment.

Comment: @Boendal Yes I have mentioned